# Jquery Validation 'validate' undefined error

Tags: jquery, validation

I have an MVC page that i am trying to add validation to but i keep getting the following error:

Unhandled exception

0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'validate'

Any ideas why?

My code is below.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#contact").validate({
            rules: {
                "name-contact": {
                    required: true
                }
            },
            messages: {
                "name-contact": {
                    required: "Please, enter a name"
                }
            },
            submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
                alert('valid form submitted'); // for demo
                return false; // for demo
            }
        });

    });
</script>


<form id="contact" method="post" action="#">
    <fieldset>
        <label for="name-contact">NAME</label>
        <input type="text" class="required input-xlarge" id="name-contact"
               name="name-contact" value="" placeholder="" minlength="2" />
        <input type="submit" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: I incorrectly have the word 'undefined' in the title. Please disregard that. It is just a Javascript error.

Comment: Seems to be working fine : http://jsfiddle.net/fz2sY/998/ . As @brendan pointed out, you might not be using the correct API.

Comment: Yeah, i actually copied the code i am using from another demo from jsfiddle. But when i try recreating it locally i get the error. Which doesnt make sense. I made sure i have downloaded the plugin from nuget and included it on the page

Comment: Try this link from CDN in your code : https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.14.0/jquery.validate.js

Comment: I added the link from the CDN you suggested and get the same error. Is there a compatibility issue with .net 4.5 or MVC 4 possibly?

Comment: It's a js file and does not have any association to .net components. I would recommend to uninstall the nuget package you installed and then try again.

Answer (score 0):

There's a good chance you're not actually importing `jquery.validate.js`.  Are you sure it's not called `jquery.validate.min.js`?  Are you sure you have the correct path?

Comment: I am dragging and dropping the scripts onto the page so the paths should be correct. I also tried with the min.js file with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. I was including the jquery bundle on the _layout page which included the following:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
```

Once i removed that the validation worked properly. I am not sure why that is causing issues but removing it allows the validate to work.